# Toggle the selection on and off using only keyboard shortcuts in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I want to remove duplicates in excel using keyboard only. After pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, how does one select/deselect the required columns with keyboard. There must be some way to do this using keyboard only, so how to toggle the selection on/off?

(In the image below, I used the mouse to select column B. how could it have been done using the keyboard)

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sequence works for me in Excel 2010 (I'd expect it to work in 2013 as well):

1. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>
3. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> 4 times
4. Press <kbd>Down</kbd> to reach the desired column
5. Press <kbd>Space</kbd> to toggle columns on/off as required
6. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm selection

Comment: thanks a ton andi, i had been stuck on this apparently simple problem for the last couple hours!

Comment: @user221238 if it is a solution to your problem, please mark the question as answered.

Comment: i kind of dont know how to mark the question as answered......hope tht putting a tick to the left of the best answer will suffice

Comment: That's it! Glad this helped you.